# How to know if an react component is visible while user scrolls page

Tags: react-redux

Want to track if the react component is visible/hidden while user vertical scrolls the page. The page is rendered by looping the through JSON response inside the component.

Comment: Add some code sample that you are using or if any approaches that you have tried.

Comment: Hi Akshay, its a dev project code, so couldn't paste it here. I'm looping through JSON response object and rendering the content using react component. When user vertical scrolls the browser page, want to know which content user is viewing. Based on the content, will be triggering some other actions.